# 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, pygame

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\ZombieGameImages\ZombielandI_NLoo.py", line 27, in <module>
gm.over(True)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

if gm.time<1: #function that causes error
   gm.over(True)
```

The error above appears when I attempt to use if gm.time<1 in my program.
I'm learning Python in school, so I'm still new to Python.
Help?

Comment: please provide some code. It is easier to understand that way.

Comment: Seems like the `gm.over` is a `bool`. What is `gm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gm.over is bool type and you call it like method...
set it like this:

```
gm.over = True
```